# How to create and populate a dynamic html table with data from a DTO

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, dto, html-table

I want to display on a JSP page a dynamic HTML table using JSTL.
(The data to be inserted into the table comes in the form of a Vector of  (the DTOs contain a number of parameters such as name, email, address, phone etc... ))
Thanks.

Comment: Look at similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362564/recommended-jsp-table-taglib

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.java-forums.org/javaserver-pages-jsp-jstl/30404-iterating-over-array-objects-jstl.html
This is a very good example,Try the above code.In that code Demo class is nothing but the DTO.
Thanks